# How to resolve Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, netbeans-7

I am trying to run the code but I have been experienceing this below error..

Using JBOSS 4.0.5 server, Netbeans 7

could anyone please help me resolve this issue?

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project plant: Error loading property file 'C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxx\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\plant\src\main\filters\${env}.properties' -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

the unresolved reference in the path you have there:

```
src\main\filters\${env}.properties
```

suggests that the maven project requires the property "env" to be set to something, possibly a *.properties file name. since youre not providing/setting this property it is left as-is and your project fails to find a file called

```
${env}.properties
```

if youre running maven from the command line you can set the property same as any java property:

```
mvn [your normal maven arguments] -Denv=something
```

if youre running it from any IDE im sure there's a way to provide the properties as well.

Comment: thank you! I changed it to local in POM.xml "<filter>src/main/filters/local.properties</filter> " and am able build the War files

Comment: @user2653936 - youre welcome. if my answer indeed resolved your issue, would you please mark it as an answer? thanks :-)